# Upload Image and insert in Database MySQl withAjax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

i m user JQuery mobile and PHP and Ajax to upload Image and insert it in Database,but i have a probleme in insert the name of image in a database,the result in database is :"C:fakepathLighthouse.jpg",i would insert just the name of image after upload it.
Mu code in php

```
      <?php // You need to add server side validation and better error handling here

     $data = array();

     if(isset($_GET['files']))
    {   
   $error = false;
   $files = array();
  £fichier=basename($file['name'];
   $uploaddir = 'photo/';
   foreach($_FILES as $file)

         {if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir. $fichier)))                                                                                        
          {
                $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
        }
        else
        {
          $error = true;
          }
               }
            $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your                                   files') : array('files' => $files);
                 }
        else
        {
   $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
         } 

      echo json_encode($data);

        ?>
```

my code script:

```
        $(function()
        {
// Variable to store your files
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

      $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server   its a query string request
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
          {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                submitForm(event, data);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
       }

   function submitForm(event, data)
  {
    // Create a jQuery object from the form
    $form = $(event.target);

    // Serialize the form data
    var formData = $form.serialize();

    // You should sterilise the file names
    $.each(data.files, function(key, value)
    {
        formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
        console.log('nom de l image:' + '&filenames[]=' + value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}
   });
```

my initial page(index.html)

```
function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
 } 
 //Get the latitude and the longitude;
  function successFunction(position) {


     var latt = position.coords.latitude;
   var lngg = position.coords.longitude;
var nom=$('input[id=nom]').val();
var photo= $('input[id=file_upload]').val();
var ville= $('input[id=ville]').val();
var pays= $('input[id=pays]').val();
long.value="Longitude: " + lngg;
   lat.value="Latitude: " + latt;

//var adr="Sousse";
codeLatLng(latt, lngg);
// var adresse=codeLatLng(latt, lngg);

  var sendAjax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'api.php?rquest=insertMosque',
   data:   'lat='+latt+'&lng='+lngg+'&nom='+nom+'&pays='+pays+'&ville='+ville+'&photo='+photo,
    success: handleResponse
  });

  function handleResponse(){
  $('#answer').get(0).innerHTML = sendAjax.responseText;
  //console.log(data);
  }

}

function errorFunction(){
  alert("Geocoder failed");
}
}



code api.php
   private function insertMosque() {
    if ($this->get_request_method() != "POST") {
        $this->response('', 406);
    }

    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $lat =($_POST['lat']);
 $lng = $_POST['lng'];
 $adr = $_POST['adr'];
 $ville = $_POST['ville'];
          $pays = $_POST['pays'];

$photo=$_POST['photo'];
       //$photo =  addslashes($file['name']);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mosque VALUES('', '$nom', '$lng','$lat',' $photo','$adr','$ville','$pays')", $this->db);
    if ($query) {
        $data['success'] = 'Insertion avec success';
    } else {
        $data['errors'] = 'failed';
    }
    $this->response($this->json($data), 200);
  }
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your question is. Do you want to upload only the filename of the uploaded photo instead of the file path? Please clarify, perhaps with an example of your expected behaviour.

Comment: i want to insert the filname of image in Database(Mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) function in your `api.php` to parse the filepath you are getting from POST:

```
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$lat =($_POST['lat']);
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$adr = $_POST['adr'];
$ville = $_POST['ville'];
$pays = $_POST['pays'];

//for example, say $_POST['photo'] = "C:/my/fake/directory/testfile.jpg"
$photopath = explode("/", $_POST['photo']);

//print_r($photopath) results in Array ( [0] => C: [1] => my [2] => fake [3] => directory [4] => testfile.jpg )

$photo = end($photopath); //gets last result in the array (your filename)

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mosque VALUES('', '$nom', '$lng','$lat',' $photo','$adr','$ville','$pays')", $this->db);
```

Please note that this may not be the most efficient method of getting the filename from a path, and your delimiter (`"/"` in the example above) might need to change based on how you are getting your path. If you have any questions feel free to ask.